# Why does the conductivity of a conductivity probe decease if you shake the solution in which it is kept?

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

Figure showing $3M$ solution $\ce{NaOH}$ conductivity while shaking (The circled area is the time of shaking and drop)
[image]

When I took the reading again, without shaking, I got the following graph:
[image]